# Regular expression to identify two same consecutive line

Tags: regex, bison, flex-lexer

I am parsing one file using flex/bison and I want to know how to identify same consecutive line.

```
 Example:

BEGIN BLOCK BLK1    

BEGIN BLOCK BLK_ROWDEC
```

How can I write regular expression to identify this two line that starting with BEGIN.

I have tried

```
^BEGIN(.*)\r?\n^BEGIN(.*)
```

But it is not identifying my string.

Please help me to parse this string.

Comment: Try `/^BEGIN\b(.*)\r?\n\s*^BEGIN\b(.*)/m`.

Comment: "lex.l", line 45: unknown error processing section 1
"lex.l", line 95: fatal parse error       It gives error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below regex will identify these two lines.

```
^BEGIN(.*)\r?\n+\s*BEGIN(.*)
```